# How to access to VPS without SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, vps, virtual-machines

The provider de-activate and re-activate my VPS account. Now everything seems to be OK on control panel (SolusVM), but my IP is not responding, and I cannot access to my server via SSH. He says this is a misconfiguration or firewall settings within the VE blocking external access, and a re-install is needed. How can I access to my server to at least take a backup of my data?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the admin of the physical server can login via chroot to your VPS and fix the firewall problem (if it's that). Ask him to do it.

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question: Why don't you already have a backup?

Comment: No excuse for my fault; but I made backup with SolusVM central backup which is now on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your firewall is not allowing any connections, and you can not get into your server. I'm afraid physical is the only solution.

Ask your provider for a dump of your virtual machine or ask them to shut down your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask your provider to boot your VM with a livedisk and set up SSH. This way you can still access your data, make a backup, and even change the configuration if you think you have found the culprit.